# How to use multiple cookies in FFmpeg?

Tags: cookies, ffmpeg, download, http-headers, http-live-streaming

I am trying to use cookies in ffmpeg to download a video that requires cookies

I checked the documentation for multiple cookies using the "-cookies" argument, they must be separated by a newline, but the docs don't show an example of how to do it, there is only an example for the cookies syntax using a single cookie. I've tried "\n" and "\r\n" (used by the "-headers" argument) and they didn't work: I get a 403 response error

Using a regular HTTP client such as curl or aiohttp (python) downloads the video, so the cookies and headers I provided are correct

**First test: Cookies as headers**

```
ffprobe -i "https://cdn12.tokyvideo.com/videos/215/215164/mp4/d41bdb167b322ab0b5bf03e9cd64c4c2edb5939e9ba56403afb52297c2ae97be.mp4?nva=20230227154655&nvb=20230223154655&token=0fe81937ec54cc94ab459" -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0" -headers "Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Host: www.tokyvideo.com
Referer: https://www.tokyvideo.com
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNzMGJQb3duNVVNNFJFS0VUdW5MV3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMWhQRlVlUUxST01IblFXdFM3ZVQzYUZHd2ZRamdGR2JCejNpSmhaMHlwSjBwcksyeHF0UWRsZFhQd244ZW9wTzNsbmdBd2JiM2luTjR2TVhxdEdNdGJQaXE3S3BJM2J5WVljaEtXbFRMRm1aUjVTS2hQVDFVWkphUkc0bjBZSUsiLCJtYWMiOiI0ODJjZjIxZjkzZGQyZjU2YTAzNjNlYzQxMGU5YTQxYjdlZGZkZGJjYWFiZGNhYzRlMzBhZTZiY2MyYjA5OTI3In0%3D; Domain=tokyvideo.com; expires=Sat, 04-Mar-2023 15:46:56 GMT; Max-Age=604800; Path=/
Cookie: tokyvideo_session=eyJpdiI6InVEUkxxUmdTZDJtZnNmeWpqaE9mTWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid1kzVTVZbmtpRHJDUDZOc25pMnRMOFBCRk1IOTVXN3dMc3Y5MmlzaGh6NzVZM0xOMlNCOTB5bTFIemdLXC9ZWE14UGhKUHN2OEFJZDZhR241bG5FcGw0aHpHeTRnbUF0cGVVUkVqQUhReXllVTY1TmtGM2hsV0w5a3RxdCtBa09JIiwibWFjIjoiNzUxM2M1MTJiN2RiM2ZmOGZkYzViM2FkY2E1NTgwNjQzY2NjODIyNWQ4ZjRkMWUxZjc5ODU3NzQyZTQ4ZjJiZiJ9; Domain=tokyvideo.com; expires=Sat, 04-Mar-2023 15:46:56 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=604800; Path=/
```

Returns 403

**Second test: Cookies using -cookies the argument**

```
ffprobe -i "https://cdn12.tokyvideo.com/videos/215/215164/mp4/d41bdb167b322ab0b5bf03e9cd64c4c2edb5939e9ba56403afb52297c2ae97be.mp4?nva=20230227154655&nvb=20230223154655&token=0fe81937ec54cc94ab459" -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0" -headers "Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Host: www.tokyvideo.com
Referer: https://www.tokyvideo.com
" -cookies "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNzMGJQb3duNVVNNFJFS0VUdW5MV3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMWhQRlVlUUxST01IblFXdFM3ZVQzYUZHd2ZRamdGR2JCejNpSmhaMHlwSjBwcksyeHF0UWRsZFhQd244ZW9wTzNsbmdBd2JiM2luTjR2TVhxdEdNdGJQaXE3S3BJM2J5WVljaEtXbFRMRm1aUjVTS2hQVDFVWkphUkc0bjBZSUsiLCJtYWMiOiI0ODJjZjIxZjkzZGQyZjU2YTAzNjNlYzQxMGU5YTQxYjdlZGZkZGJjYWFiZGNhYzRlMzBhZTZiY2MyYjA5OTI3In0%3D; Domain=tokyvideo.com; expires=Sat, 04-Mar-2023 15:46:56 GMT; Max-Age=604800; Path=/;
tokyvideo_session=eyJpdiI6InVEUkxxUmdTZDJtZnNmeWpqaE9mTWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid1kzVTVZbmtpRHJDUDZOc25pMnRMOFBCRk1IOTVXN3dMc3Y5MmlzaGh6NzVZM0xOMlNCOTB5bTFIemdLXC9ZWE14UGhKUHN2OEFJZDZhR241bG5FcGw0aHpHeTRnbUF0cGVVUkVqQUhReXllVTY1TmtGM2hsV0w5a3RxdCtBa09JIiwibWFjIjoiNzUxM2M1MTJiN2RiM2ZmOGZkYzViM2FkY2E1NTgwNjQzY2NjODIyNWQ4ZjRkMWUxZjc5ODU3NzQyZTQ4ZjJiZiJ9; Domain=tokyvideo.com; expires=Sat, 04-Mar-2023 15:46:56 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=604800; Path=/;"
```

Returns 403, using either "\n" or "\r\n" to split the cookies

Output:

```
  built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[https @ 0x557191d9b840] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
https://cdn12.tokyvideo.com/videos/215/215164/mp4/d41bdb167b322ab0b5bf03e9cd64c4c2edb5939e9ba56403afb52297c2ae97be.mp4?nva=20230227154655&nvb=20230223154655&token=0fe81937ec54cc94ab459: Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `cURL` to download the file and take care of providing the HTTP cookies (separated with `;`) and then pipe the output to `ffprobe`, which does not support sending HTTP cookies.

```
curl --cookie "a_cookie=a_value; another_cookie=another_value" https://cdn12.tokyvideo.com/videos/215/215164/mp4/d41bdb167b322ab0b5bf03e9cd64c4c2edb5939e9ba56403afb52297c2ae97be.mp4 --output - | ffprobe -i -
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this will work OK for normal files like the one in my question, but i'm having the same problem with M3U8 streams, and that is why I was using ffmpeg and not curl

Comment: Indeed, since `ffprobe` actually runs multiple HTTP requests to retrieve the full list of resolutions and the number of segments (.ts files), along with downloading the first two segments for each resolution, `cURL` won't help unless you can script its behaviour (the same `curl + ffprobe` combination can be run on `.m3u8` and `.ts` files separately).